# Насколько безопасноть включать сжатие у одной колонки в таблице на Prod под нагрузкой?

Tags: ydb

Насколько безопасно делать ALTER TABLE ... ADD FAMILY ... (COMPRESSION = "lz4", ...) , т. е.включить сжатие у одной колонки в продовой таблице под нагрузкой?
Насколько агрессивный compaction, какую долю ресурсов базы он будет потреблять? Не повлияет ли это на обработку продовой нагрузки?
И как будет весть себя база в именно момент включения, стоит ли ожидать каких-нибудь деградаций, или всё обычно проходит незаметно? Как можно оценить, насколько вырастет потребление CPU после включения сжатия?
И как именно работает сжатие колонки: для каждой строки независимо или есть какой-то общий словарь для нескольких строк? Если в разных строках есть повторяющиеся данные, то YDB сможет эту избыточность эффективно пожать?
Сжатие для клиента проходит прозрачно, то есть ничего не поменяется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На производительность заметно влиять не должно, но лучше убедиться в этом на своей нагрузке в тестах.
Обычно это проходит без происшествий. В момент включения данные не начнут сжиматься, компрессия будет произведена впоследствии в стандартном режиме. Для пользователя всё будет прозрачно.